# Evaluate : $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{1\over 4+8k+6k^2+2k^3}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am attempting a calculation for an integral and encounter this series:

$$S=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{1\over 4+8k+6k^2+2k^3}$$

but I am stuck and find it difficult to evaluate its sum.

Can someone offer suggestions?

**My Attempt:**

Factorising: 
$$4+8k+6k^2+2k^3 = 2(k+1)(k^2+2k+2)$$

$S=0.3359329927...$

$1=A(k^2+2k+2)+(Bk+C)(2k+2)$

$A=1$

Comment: [Factorising $4+8k+6k^2+2k^3$ is quite impossible](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4%2B8k%2B6k%5E2%2B2k%5E3)

Comment: Thnak you, I see it a factor of $k+1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe you have
\begin{align}
4+8k+6k^2+2k^3 =2(k+1)(k+1+i)(k+1-i)
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{4+8k+6k^2+2k^3} = \frac{1}{4i(k+1)(k+1-i)}-\frac{1}{4i(k+1).(k+1+i)}
\end{align}
Then we have
\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{1}{4+8k+6k^2+2k^3} =&\ \frac{1}{4}\sum^\infty_{k=1}\left( \frac{-i}{k(k-i)}+\frac{i}{k(k+i)}\right)\\
=&\ \frac{1}{4}\left( \psi_0(1-i)+\psi_0(1+i)+2\gamma\right)
\end{align}
where $\psi_0$ is the digamma function and $\gamma$ is the Euler–Mascheroni constant.

I have used the fact that
\begin{align}
\psi_0(z+1) = -\gamma+\sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{z}{k(k+z)}.
\end{align}

Comment: I believe the sign of $\gamma$ and the summation index are wrong in the last expression.

Comment: This beautifully reduces to $\frac{1}{4} \left(H_{-i}+H_i\right)$

Comment: Hi @Claude Leibovici is this the closed form? When Imaginary part is involved I can't understand it.

Comment: @black. It is the same as Jacky Chong's expression (he also has $i$ in the expression).

Comment: @black. The question is what is the most suitable form for your calculation. Obviously the final function is real.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
S & \equiv \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over 4 + 8k + 6k^{2} + 2k^{3}} =
{1 \over 2}\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over k^{3} + k} =
{1 \over 2}\Im\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over k\pars{k - \ic}}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2}\,\Im\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{k + 1}\pars{k + 1 - \ic}} =
{1 \over 2}\,\Im\bracks{\Psi\pars{1} - \Psi\pars{1 - \ic} \over \ic} =
{1 \over 2}\,\Im\bracks{\ic\gamma + \ic\Psi\pars{1 - \ic}}
\\[5mm] & = \bbx{\gamma + \Re\Psi\pars{1 - \ic} \over 2} =
\bbx{{1 \over 2}\,\Re\pars{H_{-\ic}}} \approx 0.3359
\end{align}